# Exported .csv file from SQL Server is returning null values in HIVE

Tags: sql, sql-server, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have exported a table in .csv format from SQL Server 2008 in ANSI encoding. I loaded it into HDFS and ran a create table command in HIVE. I've done this for 25 other tables with success, but for some reason this table is returning null values. [This is the table schema from SQL Server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54yFe.png)

My HIVE code:

```
--creates corresponding table in staging for Job
create external table staging.Job(
    jobid int  
    ,datasourceid int 
    ,regionid int 
    ,jobsrcid varchar(20) 
    ,jobnumber varchar(80) 
    ,info1 varchar(40) 
    ,info2 varchar(40) 
    ,info3 varchar(40) 
    ,info4  varchar(40) 
    ,info5  varchar(40) 
    ,info6  varchar(40) 
    ,info7  varchar(40) 
    ,info8  varchar(40) 
    ,info9  varchar(40) 
    ,info10 varchar(40) 
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
-- stored as textfile to be compatible for importing a csv file  
stored as textfile
LOCATION 'hdfs://[HDFS PATH]/staging/Job' 
-- this command skips over the header line for the csv files
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1")
;

--uploaded csv files first into HDFS, so no need for a -local argument
LOAD DATA INPATH '/labrat/Job2.csv' INTO TABLE staging.Job;

SELECT * from staging.Job;
```

Originally this table was giving my issues with one of the columns, stating that it was using a DT_NTEXT format or something. I did a SELECT statement on all columns but that problematic one and exported those.

Comment: The whole Hadoop ecosystem uses UTF-8, so I strongly advise you to export in UTF-8 instead of your undescript "ANSI" *(do you mean `ISO-8859-1` or `ISO-8859-15` or `Windows-1252`? or something else?)*

Comment: To clarify, for the ANSI I meant Windows-1252. I just tried using UTF-8 (65001) and it gave me the same null values. The raw data itself is fine, I checked both the .csv files in each encoding.

Comment: What about showing a few examples of records, as shown from *(a)* a text editor and *(b)* the result of an Impala query? Don't you think it would help us to help you instead of just saying *"I've got a problem, I won't explain, now just send me some wild guesses"* ?

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. [Here is the link. Left is the raw file displayed in Notepad++, right portion is my Hive output in Hue.](https://imgur.com/bOqrxCP)

Comment: Yuck - what kind of **encoding** does Notepad++ report for the initial CSV file?? *(it's quite good at handling bizarre stuff and therefore hides problems that will hit other tools)*

Comment: One empty record after each regular record => my guess is the LOAD command messed your Windows End-Of-Line (data-CR-LF) and now you get data-LF-LF. // Column missing in table definition, values are not properly aligned => your mistake // Integer values messed up => no idea.

Comment: You should change all column types to STRING, then make a dump of one of the generated "textfile" to check for non-printable chars etc -- sthg like `hdfs dfs -tail /blah/blah//staging/Job/xxxxx | od -cx`